# Magento Installation stuck at Localization

Tags: magento

I tried to install fresh magento but Magento Installation stuck at Localization step during installation.

Please advise if you kow how to solve the problem?

regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

The 500 error indicates an internal server failure which can be caused by a programming error in any system of your site or by incorrect permissions on files and folders. Contact your server, or change the permissions to 755 (folders) 644 ( files) or using magento cleanup tool .

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the tip
the issues were the permission 
I ran the following and solved

chmod -R o+w media var
chmod o+w app/etc